# Hooking SK in sandstorm doesn't cancel his sandstorm. So Is SK still invisible away from the sandstorm?

Tags: dota-2, dota

I was playing Pudge. Tried to save an ally Sand King so i hooked him in sandstorm. Hooked him successfully but the sandstorm's animation was in the hero's previous position.
Will SK still be invisible near me until he moves??
Where will the enemies get damaged?Is it Near the current position of SK or the place of sandstorm's animation?

Comment: are you sure its not cancelled?  It could just be the fade delay.

Comment: No its not cancelled but i couldnt find whether he was invisible or not since the ally moved the hero within few seconds

Comment: @kotsu This happened to me while WC3 Dota so adding the tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Sand King will remain invisible and will still be channeling Sandstorm until he moves. While the animation will stay in the original spot, enemies will only get damaged in Sand King's new location (where you hooked him to).

See the following video for reference:

The visual effect not moving to Sand King's new location is likely a bug that Valve hasn't gotten around to fixing yet.

Comment: And moreover is it same for Toss, Swap and Eza's TP?

Comment: @PremAnand It depends on if those skills interrupt channeling spells. Off hand, I think Toss will interrupt spells such as Sandstorm or Rhasta's Shackles.